# Design view for windows universal apps in Visual studio 2015

Tags: windows, visual-studio, win-universal-app

I downloaded VS2015 community edition today and started developing a universal app, but I surprised to see that their is no design view in it for the corresponding Xaml pages. I enabled the design view in tools->options->xml designer->general -> endabled the design view. but no use.

Am I missing some thing ?

How to enable it, if any one solved this Issue please do share.

Thanks

Comment: What OS are you on? The Xaml designer for Universal Windows apps requires Windows 10.

Comment: Try looking for some small buttons at the bottom right of the Xmal editor window. There should be one with <<.

Comment: I am using windows 10. Their is no such button. previously I used VS13, It was all fine. I could easily switch between Design mode and Xml mode. after upgraded to VS15 community edition I am getting this Issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a target version Build 10586 for your project, you need to go back to the older version 10240. Looks like there is some bug in the new one.

[image]